# Обновление таблицы многие ко многим. EntityFramework

Tags: sql, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework

Пусть есть три таблицы A, B, C. C - содержит ключи A и B, ну и связывает их естественно. Миграция создавалась с двумя сущностями, но сейчас нужна сущность для таблицы C. При попытке прикрепления новой сущности к таблице C(и через fluent и через аннотации) миграция пытается затереть таблицу C, переименовывая в таблицу C1, и создать ту же самую таблицу C. Может кто знает как можно прикрепить новую сущность к существующей таблице? Спасибо!

Comment: + 1 мне тоже интересно узнать.Терпеть не могу code first, но будет интересно узнать. Мы в своё время добавляли ещё одну колонку в "С" (просто пустое битовое поле) и это решало проблему, заставляя EF явно генерировать таблицу. Но это если изначально проектировать.